# Critical points of a function and discontinuity

Tags: derivatives

I just wanted to ask, why does the following function:

$$f(x)=x^{1/3}(x+3)^{2/3}$$

Have 3 crtical points $0,-1,-3$, because its first derivative is:

$$f'(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}(x+3)^{1/3}}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^{2/3}(x+3)^{1/3}}=0$$

Then $x=-1$ is the critical point as its undefined on $-3$, and $0$, so why is $-3$, and $0$ also considered a critical point$?$

Comment: @caverac Why need $x \ge 0$? Those are *cuberoots* in the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A critical point $c$ is where $f(c)$ defined, and $f'(c)$ either zero or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** *critical points any limit points where the function may be prolongated by continuity or where the derivative is not defined.*
or
a critical point or stationary point of a differentiable function of a real or complex variable is any value in its domain where its derivative is 0.

Comment: Note that the function needs to be defined at the critical point. No "prolongation by continuity" is used in the definition.

Comment: some authors mentioned this point

Comment: John-- I'd say if one prolongs a domain by conytinuity one is working with a different function.